# Elasticsearch won't find any results for a search containing symbols

Tags: java, elasticsearch

I'm begining with elasticsearch in java.

I can make a query that matches documents having a property containing a text. This property is a string.

The results are strange: when I'm searching for a string containing the symbol '-', I have no results

Here is a summary of the current behavior:

I have 2 documents :

```
{
  model:"123",
  serialNumber: "tt-1"
}
```

and

```
{
  model:"123",
  serialNumber: "tt-2"
}
```

If I'm searching for "tt" I have 2 results => OK

If I'm searching for "tt-", I have no results.

I'm using wildcard.

Here is a sample of my code:

```
BoolQueryBuilder bqb = new BoolQueryBuilder();
bqb.should(new WildcardQueryBuilder("serialNumber", "tt*"));

return QueryBuilders.filteredQuery(bqb, null);
```

Thanks for your help

Comment: What version of elasticsearch are you using?

Comment: Check this out: https://www.elastic.co/blog/found-beginner-troubleshooting